# Declaring a route overrides another

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.6

When declaring a route with a parameter, Laravel somehow disregards any other route that's declared right after (any route that has the name naming convention).

This is my `routes.php` file

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth','member'], 'prefix' => 'profile'], function () {
     Route::get('/details/{profile_id}','Member\ProfileController@index');
     Route::get('/details/image','Member\ProfileImageController@index');
     Route::get('/details/details','Member\ProfileDetailsController@index');
});
```

When trying to pull the `profile image`, I keep getting `Requested resource could not be found`, but if I declare `/details/image` before `/details/{profile_id}`, then it works.

Could it be that Laravel matches `{profile_id}` with `image`? I couldn't find anything on the Laravel doc that would state this would be the case.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Why would it *not* match? :-)  How can Laravel know that `image` is not a valid `{profile_id}`?  You have to either change the order of your routes, or specify what a `profile_id` should look like using a regular expression, [as described in the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing#parameters-regular-expression-constraints).

Answer (score 0):

You have to arrange the routes in this way. because `/details/image` will be considered as `/details/*`.

```
 Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth','member'], 'prefix' => 'profile'], function () {

     Route::get('/details/image','Member\ProfileImageController@index');
     Route::get('/details/details','Member\ProfileDetailsController@index');
     Route::get('/details/{profile_id}','Member\ProfileController@index');

 });
```

Or you can also use filters to get the exact value

```
Route::get('/details/{profile_id}','Member\ProfileController@index')->where('profile_id', '[0-9]+');
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to except `public function endix` that uses this route `Route::get('/details/image','Member\ProfileImageController@index');`

> on your controller put this

```
public function__construct(){
      {$this->middleware('auth', ['except' => ['index']]);
}
```

or you could change it because index is a unique function.